# How to repair MBR and the like after installing ubuntu on a portable hard drive

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu on a portable hard drive with my main hard drive unplugged so as not to mess up anything on there. Ubuntu installed just fine so I unplugged that and plugged my main drive back up but when it starts up it says no boot-able medium is found. I've used boot repair from Ubuntu on a flash drive and it went through it with no errors and it said you can now reboot your computer. I did and it still said the same thing. As far as I can see everything is still on my main drive with windows 10. The computer is a Dell Inspiron 3650 running in UEFI mode. Under the boot selection menu it gives me Ubuntu and the main drive.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I can rub boot repair again and follow up with the logs if need be.

Comment: did you set boot priority back to the main drive?

Comment: If external drive, UEFI only boots from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. But your install of Ubuntu should have in the ESP - efi system partition /EFI/ubuntu. You need to copy /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi to /EFI/Boot and rename to bootx64.efi.  Boot-Repair may automatically do copy if you use "use standard efi file" in advanced options. Make sure internal is still unplugged and you boot live installer in UEFI mode. If that does not work post link to summary report from Boot-Repair.

Comment: @oldfred - he removed the ubuntu drive and put his windows drive back in

Comment: I have used the method you describe (unplug the internal drive while installing into an external drive). It has worked well several times for me. If you have not changed anything else, for example in the UEFI/BIOS system of the computer, it should boot from the internal drive, when connected again. Try to remember if you changed something, and change it back. -- It is an advantage to unplug the external drive, before starting Windows, otherwise the external drive's bootloader can be damaged.

Comment: @ravery you mean from the bios?

Comment: well it isn't BIOS. it is EFI firmware,  but yes

Comment: @sudodus everything is still the same in the bios I even used the "Reset to default settings" to make sure. Bios read the internal drive it just doesn't boot into windows as it should. I think something may be wrong with the bootmgr or the MBR of the main drive. What files should be in the main directory of the windows drive for it to be able to boot? I have the files as follows. bootmgr, BOOTNXT, dell.sdr, fiod.sdr, hiverfil.sys, pagefile.sys, and swapfile.sys

Comment: @ravery do you have any exerience with the dell "BIos/ EFI firmware"? I ask because I'm not sure exactly where I should go to set the boot priority

Comment: I'm no longer good at troubleshooting Windows. *But it should not be damaged*, unless you made a 'hard shutdown', that might have damaged the file system of the system partition of Windows, C: -- A possible repair method is to use a 'recovery disk' for Windows, if you made one before this advanture, or a Windows install drive (you can download a Windows iso file from Microsoft and make a DVD install disk or USB install drive).

Comment: EFI doesn't use the MBR. there is a slim chance that you win10 is not installed in UEFI mode. I'm not familiar with Dell, but there should be a section for boot options. there you can turn secure boot on/off, enable/disable legacy/CSM suport, and change boot order. If win10 is EFI mode, there will be a EFI system partition on the drive. windows boots from the file /EFI/boot/bootx64.efi

Comment: @sudodus windows 10 came preinstalled so no disk but I have another working computer so I'll look into the ISO file from Microsoft and follow up on how that goes.

Comment: @ravery as far as I know windows 10 came preinstalled under UEFI mode. Looking at the boot options I have ubuntu, and two boot options over Ethernet and nothing more

Comment: double check the connections on the HDD. Does the HDD show in the system info section?

Comment: @ravery the windows 10 hard drive does show up in the bios settings

Comment: please reboot with your installation media, run the command `sudo fdisk -l` and [edit] the output into your question.

Comment: @elder geek use terminal from the ubuntu live cd?

Comment: Yes please. Preferably with both the drives attached.

Comment: Many Dell have UEFI setting for drives as RAID or Intel SRT which looks like RAID. Ubuntu prefers AHCI and supposedly RAID setting includes AHCI. but Windows requires you to install AHCI into Windows 10 before changing UEFI to RAID. But you should be able to change back to boot Windows, but then Ubuntu will not work. My Dell 3647 just worked without issue for dual booting. But I upgraded to Windows 10 from 8 after installing dual boot.